# virutalbox always get back the same ip

Tags: virtualbox, udev, ip-address

I exported a virtual machine from my work station, and I am trying to renew the ip-address at home. I put one copy on my laptop and one copy on my PC.

I've done this

```
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

and changed the MAC address, but they keep coming back as 192.168.1.165. I need them to be different because I need to run two of these exports at the same time, so I cannot afford to have the same IP.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Virtual Box (I use VMware Player) but for the NIC config you should be able to change it from NAT to bridged. That should allow a different IP.

Comment: They are both Bridged. Are you saying try set to NAT first then back to Bridged? Thanks.

Comment: No, NAT should pass traffic through the host whereas bridged should allow a different IP. At least that's how it is in VMware Player and I don't see why that would be different in virtual box.

Can you set a static IP on one of the hosts instead of relying on DHCP? Or if possible, set a DHCP reservation on one?

Oh... and before that, did you try taking down the interface and bringing it back up so the settings would take effect?

Comment: @CoreWhitake Yes I have reboot, shutdown, after taking down the interface. I even unplugged my cable, reboot, and plug back and turn on again to force it to "realize" it needs a new one. I will try to set a static one. Not sure if it's possible.